# How to add samesite = strict to JSESSIONID cookie in weblogic server either using servlet or configuration file itself?

Tags: servlets, weblogic, jsessionid

I am working on SameSite attribute Vulnerability in AppSpider.

When first time we send `JSESSIONID` cookie in response's `SameSite` attribute should be strict. How to make it happen?
By default it sends this much:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=11V1VyWSUBJD5Cn8boKVCZzBpGOUe7NP5xEkkrEXtl5ypBkFeQdr!-1972425066; path=/; HttpOnly
```

in response. I want to add `SameSite` as well. When I edit the `weblogic.xml` file then changes are not reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve this with the weblogic.xml depoloyment descriptor. You have to write a Filter (javax.servlet.Filter) to add this attribute to your cookies. Your filter should read all cookies from the response and add them the samesite attribute.
Another solution is to update your cookies within an HTTP server in front of your WebLogic Server instances (apache, OHS, etc...)

Comment: I have done this using weblogic.xml file   <wls:session-descriptor>
     <wls:cookie-path>/;SameSite=strict</wls:cookie-path>

</wls:session-descriptor>

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to `weblogic`. xml file that is in the `WEB_INF` folder, add `<wls:session-descriptor>` then `<wls:cookie-path`>. As below:

```
<wls:session descriptor>
    <wls:cookie`enter code here`-path>/;SameSite=strict</wls:cookie-path>
</wls:session-descriptor>
```